# TF2 Game Server Map Cycle Help

Tags: team-fortress-2, hosting, server-administration

I was just wondering how I could link the start up script (tf.sh) and link it to a the mapcycle.txt file in /steamcmd/tf2/tf/cfg/mapcycle.txt... Or if there is any other way for it to change levels with out me going into the startup script file and changing it to just one map... Thanks.